# How to use array slice with a variable endpoint?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

```
let size = 1;
let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;

    if (clientHeight + scrollTop >= scrollHeight - 1) {
      size += 1;
      console.log("adding");
    }
  });

  let items = arr.slice(0, size);
  console.log(items);
```

This is a dummy array just to showcase the problem. The `items` array should receive more items from `arr` array as the user reaches the end of the page.

**How can I increase a copy of an array using the variable as an endpoint for an array?** I'm trying to run this code above but the `items` array is not being updated.

This dummy code is a pseudo example of infinite scrolling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `slice`. The problem is that the `console.log(items);` line runs only once and before the scroll event handler runs.

Here is a simpler example that demonstrates the issue. In this case `setTimeout()`'s handler takes the place of the scroll event handler.

```js
let x = 1;

setTimeout(() => {
  x = 2;
}, 0);

console.log(x); //logs 1 (not 2)
```